# SwingWorker Doesn't Work in ActionListener

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener, swingworker

In part of my email program, the user can select the message folder they want to open through a drop down `JComboBox`. This process can take up to twenty seconds depending on how many messages are in the folder, and before this would just freeze up the program. This wasn't desirable, so I utilized `SwingWorker` to run the opening of the folder in the background of the GUI and display a progress bar while the folder is being accessed.

The accessing of the folders is implemented with an `ActionListener` which listens for the folder name selected and sets the selected `String` as the name of the folder to be accessed. Here is the code for the `ActionListener`, where items is an array of folder names.

```
    box = new JComboBox<String>(items);
    box.setEditable(false);
    box.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            try
            {
                String selected = (String)box.getSelectedItem();
                if(selected.equals("Choose Folder"))
                    accessFolder(null);
                else if(selected.equals("Inbox"))
                    accessFolder("INBOX");
                else
                {
                    selected = TAG + selected;
                    accessFolder(selected);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + 
                ex.getClass().getName(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    });
```

The end result of this code is as expected: a list of all messages is added to part of the main frame. But the progress bar never shows up. But if I add the code for the `accessFolder` method directly to the main method (where the `ActionListener` is added to the combo box), the progress bar shows up for the entirety of the process and I get the same end result. This is the `accessFolder` code.

```
private void accessFolder(String folderName) throws MessagingException, IOException
{
    MessagePanel mPanel = new MessagePanel(username, password, folderName);
    panel4 = mPanel.getJPanel();   
    panel4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
    BorderLayout layout = (BorderLayout)panel3.getLayout();
    panel3.remove(layout.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.EAST));
    panel3.add(panel4, BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.pack();
    frame.revalidate();
}
```

So I can't seem to figure out why the SwingWorker (implemented in the `MessagePanel` class in `accessFolder`) works perfectly fine when implemented anywhere in the code except in an `ActionListener`. I can't seem to find anywhere a mention of a conflict between `SwingWorker` and listeners, and I don't see why there should be, leaving me completely baffled here. Thanks for any comments.

Edit: Here is the SwingWorker code.

```
public class FolderWorker extends CMailWorker
{
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String foldername;
    private FolderContents accessor;
    private ArrayList<MailList> msgList;
    private DefaultListModel<String> model;
    private ProgressBar bar;
    private final static String PENDING = "Accessing...";
    public FolderWorker(String user, String pass, String fName)
    {
        super(PENDING, null);
        this.username = user;
        this.password = pass;
        this.foldername = fName;
    }
    protected Void doInBackground()
    {
        try
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        createProgressBar();
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        setException(ex);
                   }
                }
            });
            super.throwException();
            accessor = new FolderContents(username, password, foldername);
            model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
            msgList = accessor.getMessageList();
            for(int x = msgList.size()-1; x>=0; x--)
            {
                MailList mList = msgList.get(x);
                String sub = mList.getSubject();
                model.addElement(sub);
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch(final Exception ex)
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + 
                    ex.getClass().getName(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            });
            super.setError(true);
            return null;
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<MailList> getList()
    {
        return accessor.getMessageList();
    }
    public DefaultListModel<String> getModel()
    {
        return model;
    }
}
```

And that class extends this class.

```
public class CMailWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>
{
    private ProgressBar bar;
    private String completed;
    private String message;
    private boolean error;
    private JFrame frame;
    private Exception exception;
    public CMailWorker(String msg, String done)
    {
        completed = done;
        message = msg;
        error = false;
    }
    protected Void doInBackground()
    {
        return null;
    }
    protected void done()
    {
        bar.dispose();
        if(frame != null)
            killJFrame();
        if(!error && completed != null)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, completed);
    }
    protected void setJFrame(JFrame f)
    {
        frame = f;
    }
    private void killJFrame()
    {
        frame.dispose();
    }
    protected void createProgressBar() throws InterruptedException
    {
        bar = new ProgressBar(message);
    }
    protected void setError(boolean e)
    {
        error = e;
    }
    protected boolean getError()
    {
        return error;
    }
    protected void throwException() throws Exception
    {
        if(exception != null)
            throw exception;
    }
    protected void setException(Exception e)
    {
        exception = e;
    }
    protected Exception getException()
    {
        return exception;
    }
}
```

Comment: `SwingWorker` indeed works well with `ActionListener`.  Without the code you refer to that starts the `SwingWorker` inside `MessagePanel`, I doubt anyone could guess what the problem is.

Comment: I added the SwingWorker code.

Comment: `setException()`/`throwException()` should be synchronized, since those are accessed from two different threads.  Calling `invokeLater()` from within `doInBackground()` has got to be causing some problems.  You don't know when that code will run.  I'd like to see the code for `MessagePanel`'s ctor, there's probably more errors inside there